# Admod AddTestDevice published

Tags: android, admob

I am using this line in my admob code

```
 adRequest.addTestDevice("xxxxxxxxx");
```

Does this mean it will only show test ads on MY DEVICE?

I just wanted to make sure before i mash PUBLISH on my new game.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, addTestDevice whitelists your device only for test ads.  The AdMob API prevents you from shooting yourself in the foot.